# What mathematical operation does # mean in the statement x # y = x(x-y)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I'm studying a for the GRE and a practice test problem is, "For all real numbers x and y, if x#y=x(x-y), then x#(x#y) =?

I do not know what the # sign means. This is apparently an algebra function but I cannot find any such in several searches. I'm an older student and haven't had basic algebra in over 45 years and this was certainly not in my recent linear algebra class.

Comment: They are inventing a new operation called `#`, and they are telling you how to calculate it. For instance, $2\#3 = 2(2-3) = 2(-1) = -2$.

Comment: x#y=x(x-y) is a definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in this context, $\#$ is a binary operation. It's just a notation.

It can translated to be let us define the rule of function $f$ to be
$$f(x,y) = x(x-y).$$

Evaluate $$f(x, f(x,y)).$$

Answer (score 3):

Think about it like this. Let's say I tell you that

$$a+3=5$$

and I ask you, knowing this information,

$$a+4=  \ ?$$

The same thing is going on here, but instead the makers of the question have created a new operation using the symbol $\#$ and are asking you, based on one piece of information, to deduce the expected behavior of the operator in another scenario.